# AC Motor operating region

Tags: motor, ac, speed

I've been using an ABB IRB 2400 robotic arm to gain experimental data and write a report based on the data.

I found that when I operated it at different speeds for pre-programmed paths, I got a larger variance in time taken over repeated paths at below 30-40% speed, and above 70% speed. Is this due to the AC motors in the arm having a certain operating region at which they work best with the least signal noise etc? Or is there other factors that I am missing?

My plot of the time variance is below:

[image: Time variance vs speed]

Comment: The variance is miniscule - what measurement methods did you use and have you considered the mechancial issues?

Comment: The time measurements were taken automatically using the robots internal computer. What mechanical issues would you suggest? Do you mean heating of the components or friction etc?